# Using Identity in SQL Server without race condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

So let's say you have a table of Patients with an IDENTITY(1,1) for the primary key.  By using @@Identity, how do we avoid a race condition where two people may save a new patient at the same time?  Obviously, duplicate ID's in the Patients table would not be created, but what if the application needed the ID for one of the inserted patients to update a record in another table elsewhere?  How do we know that @@Identity won't get the ID of the other record if both are inserted at the same time?

Or is there a best practice for avoiding this?

JamesNT

Comment: Well, first, you use SCOPE_IDENTITY(), not @@IDENTITY. And what race condition do you speak of? One insert will win, and get the first row, and then the other insert will follow. Each insert will get its own SCOPE_IDENTITY() value back, it's not possible for one insert to get the other's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a best practice.  Don't use `@@Identity`.

The safest way to get the identity values assigned in an `insert` statement is to use the `OUTPUT` clause.  You should start with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

This has numerous advantages:

- It does not get confused by triggers and nested statements.
- It can handle multiple inserts at the same time.
- It can return the values of other columns, not just the identity column.
- It specifically returns the rows affected by the transaction, so you don't even think about sessions, users, or anything else.

Comment: Looks like we have a tie between SCOPE_IDENTITY and OUTPUT.

Comment: How do we break this tie?

Comment: I need to be able to check BOTH answers as they both appear to work.

Comment: OUTPUT is great for getting back the row you just entered, including the identity.  But scope-identity works great as well and is suited to my needs.

Comment: @JamesNT . . . The general consensus is that `OUTPUT` is more robust, flexible, and safer.

Answer (score 3):

@@IDENTITY will not cause a race condition but it is NOT best practice either. You should instead be using SCOPE_IDENTITY.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Comment: So I do an INSERT but then have to do a SELECT on SCOPE_IDENTITY.  Question:  How do I handle the possibility that between the completion of my INSERT and the running of the SELECT that someone doesn't insert a record in the meantime?  Apologies if I sound like a n00b.

Comment: You don't have to worry about it. If another process is inserting a row it will be a different connection...thus the scope will be completely different.